# Calculate hours between two timer using asp.net mvc core

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

First i'm using Asp.net MVC core first code  , i have this code in design shift.cshtml :

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="shift_from" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="shift_from" class="form-control" type="time" />
            <span asp-validation-for="shift_from" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="shift_to" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="shift_to" class="form-control" type="time" />
            <span asp-validation-for="shift_to" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>        
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="shift_hours" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="shift_hours" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="shift_hours" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
```

And i created a Controller name "shift_1" :i do not know 
1-how i create the function that calculate between two timer ?
2-How i link the function to shift.cshtml?
3-When user click to change the timer calculate asp-for="shift_hours" will calculate auto ?
I searched a lot of 2 days but nothing found for answer , hope someone can solve or guide me .

Comment: Use `TimeSpan` class,when you minus two `DateTime` you will get `TimeSpan`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Pujangga_Malam/jtyqrfx0/3/)

```
function calculate(){
  var startTime=$('.shift_from')[0].value;
  var endTime=$('.shift_to')[0].value;
    return ( new Date("2020-5-16 " + endTime) - new Date("2020-5-16 " + startTime) ) / 
1000 / 60 / 60; 
}

$('.shift_to').change(function(){
    $('.shift_hours').val(calculate());
});
```

Comment: Thanks for replay , I tried to do this : with javascript :  <script>

        $('.shift_hours').val(calculate());

        function calculate() {
            var startTime = $('.shift_from')[0].value;
            var endTime = $('.shift_to')[0].value;
            return (new Date("2020-5-16 " + endTime) - new Date("2020-5-16 " + startTime)) / 1000 / 60 / 60;
        }

        $('.shift_to').change(function () {
            $('.shift_hours').val(calculate());
        });
    </script>     and not working

Comment: Also i tried to put this in controller : all function is error , where can i put this code and using what of parameter ,i meant using like this : void .. or public if you can explain sir.Thanks

Comment: And when i tried the code above when i choose : 11:30:PM "night" to  01:30 AM it calculate wrong with -22 and the value must be 2 hours right ?

Comment: see the [link](https://jsfiddle.net/Pujangga_Malam/jtyqrfx0/3/) and you can play around with some value. copy as well the html part, not just the script part. For 11:30PM tp 01:30AM, you should notice that 01:30 is the next day (the date should be 2020-5-17) to get 2 hours different. Otherwise it will result -22.

Comment: I did but this is static time and date what should be i do to make this is dynamic i appreciate your help.

Comment: I tried to do this line for date dynamic and not working :    return (new Date(Date.now + endTime) - new Date(Date.now + startTime)) / 1000 / 60 / 60;